# How to make the link appear in base.html in django

Tags: python, django

I am learning django, I added a new app,

the link can be displayed in friendly_link.html,

the code is as follows:

- admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import FriendlyLink

admin.site.register(FriendlyLink)
```

- models.py

```
from django.db import models

class FriendlyLink(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', verbose_name='title')
    url = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', verbose_name='url')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'links'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

- views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import FriendlyLink

def friendly_link(request):
    friendly_link = FriendlyLink.objects.order_by('title')
    context = {'friendly_link': friendly_link}
    return render(request, 'friendly_link.html', context)
```

- urls.py

```
from django.urls import re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^links$', views.friendly_link, name='friendly_link'),
]
```

- friendly_link.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Links{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<ul>
  {% for link in friendly_link %}
  <li><a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
  {% empty %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

- base.html

```
{% load i18n static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
{% block content %}{% endblock %}

<footer>
<ul>
  <!--This code doesn't work-->
  {% for link in friendly_link %}
  <li><a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
  {% empty %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
</footer>
...
</body>
```

I want to put the link inside the `<footer>` element in base.html. How do I change the code? Thank you.

Comment: as bottom means the end of the page?

Comment: Within the <footer> element in base.html

Comment: Sorry, my expression is not clear, i have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really read this documentation page:

https://django-adminlte2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates_and_blocks.html

Each block is clickable there and there's a detailed description on how to overwrite each one.

For your problem, you will probably `nav_footer`

```
{% block nav_footer %}
{{ block.super }}
...
{% endblock %}
```

`{{ block.super }}` is optional and will append your content to the block instead of overwriting it.

Comment: Sorry, my expression is not clear, i have updated the question.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: This gives me an idea. Thank you.